# Why is relative path not working in NWJS application?

Tags: javascript, html, directory, nwjs

Only absolute paths are working. This code works. If I use `../../../SYSTEM.USER/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENTS.NFO'` it won't work.

EDIT: How can I use a variable like `/%APPLICATION%/SYSTEM.USER/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENTS.NFO`? Is that possible in this manner?

`Main.js`

```
function OpenDocuments() {
    const path = require('path');
    nw.Shell.showItemInFolder(path.resolve('D:/PROTON DRIVE/PROTON.USER/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENTS.NFO'));
}
```

`Default.html`

```
<div name="FolderMenuContainer" id="FolderMenuContainer" class="FolderMenuContainer">
    <span name="FolderIcon" id="FolderIcon" class="material-icons"> description </span>
    <span name="FolderText" id="FolderText" class="FolderText" onclick="OpenDocuments()"> Documents </span>
</div>
```

`File Structure`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I use is to use `path.join` and `process.cwd()`. `cwd` means "Current Working Directory".

**Example:**

```js
const path = require('path');
const place = path.join(process.cwd(), '..', '..', 'my-folder');
```

You can also use `__dirname` which is relative to the file the code is executed from, which may be different from the Current Working Directory.

```js
const path = require('path');
const place = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'my-folder');
```

If you want to use resolve Windows environment variables, I would recommend making a helper function like this:

```js
/**
 * Replaces all environment variables with their actual value.
 * Keeps intact non-environment variables using '%'.
 *
 * @example
 * // 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\AMD64'
 * resolveWindowsEnvironmentVariables('C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%');
 *
 * @param  {string} filePath  The input file path with percents.
 * @return {string}           The resolved file path.
 */
function resolveWindowsEnvironmentVariables (filePath) {
  if (process.platform !== 'win32') {
    return filePath;
  }
  if (!filePath || typeof(filePath) !== 'string') {
    return undefined;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the value stored in the process.env for a given
   * environment variable. Or the original '%ASDF%' string if
   * not found.
   *
   * @example
   * replaceEnvironmentVariable('%USERNAME%', 'USERNAME');
   *
   * @param  {string} withPercents     '%USERNAME%'
   * @param  {string} withoutPercents  'USERNAME'
   * @return {string}                  'bob' || '%USERNAME%'
   */
  function replaceEnvironmentVariable (withPercents, withoutPercents) {
    let found = process.env[withoutPercents];
    // 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%asdf%' => 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\%asdf%'
    return found || withPercents;
  }

  // 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%' => 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\AMD64'
  filePath = filePath.replace(/%([^%]+)%/g, replaceEnvironmentVariable);

  return filePath;
}
```

You may also want to resolve non-windows paths

```js
/**
 * Resolves paths that start with a tilde to the user's
 * home directory.
 *
 * @example
 * // '/home/bob/GitHub/Repo/file.png'
 * resolveTilde('~/GitHub/Repo/file.png');
 *
 * @param  {string} filePath  '~/GitHub/Repo/file.png'
 * @return {string}           '/home/bob/GitHub/Repo/file.png'
 */
function resolveTilde (filePath) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    return filePath;
  }
  if (!filePath || typeof(filePath) !== 'string') {
    return undefined;
  }

  const os = require('os');
  // '~/folder/path' or '~' not '~alias/folder/path'
  if (filePath.startsWith('~/') || filePath === '~') {
    return filePath.replace('~', os.homedir());
  }

  return filePath;
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure i understand how to use a relative path to get from working dir of SYSTEM.CORE to SYSTEM.USER? I'm so confused on this...

Comment: do the ".." ".." back up directories in your first example?

Comment: yes it goes up a level. Never heard of SYSTEM.CORE or SYSTEM.USER. Literally no idea what that is.

Comment: Its in my pictures of the file structure of my program.

Comment: By go up a level do you mean go to the parent directory every time ".." is used?

Comment: My nwjs applications are in SYSTEM.CORE and my protable software in is SYSTEM.FILES. I need to make a relative link from within SYSTEM.CORE files to portable software exes in SYSTEM.FILES. Thats my main problem. I can only get my program to exicute the portable software via absolute paths not relative. Using absolute constricts my program to being installed in a specific drive. I want to be able to install it anywhere and the paths not be broken. Its hard to explain by text.

Comment: Ill Literally cashapp you a few bucks or something if you contact me and help me figure this out. Im still learning a lot of stuff and this is really turning my head right now.

Comment: Figured it out thank to you bro. Thank you. I was just simply not comprehending a few things. I got it now thought!

Comment: Youre a G.O.A.T. !!! I LOVE THIS COMMUNITY SO HELPFUL!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out thanks to Jaredcheeda! The specific solution to my problem is this:

```
function RunNotePad() {
    const path = require('path');
    nw.Shell.openItem(path.join(process.cwd(), '..', '..', '..', 'PROTON.FILES/PROGRAM.FILES/V8.4.2_NotePad++', 'notepad++.exe'));
}
```

Each '..' moves backwards a directory. I tried using the ../../../ in my file path in my original code and it wasn't working. Using the method Jerod explained it is working!

Comment: For `path.join` each folder should be passed in separately, so `path` will be in charge of adding in the appropriate slashes based on OS. You probably want `__dirname` instead of `process.cwd()`.
`function openNotepadPlusPlus () {
  const path = require('path');
  const npp = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'PROTON.FILES', 'PROGRAM.FILES', 'V8.4.2_NotePad++', 'notepad++.exe');
  nw.Shell.openItem(npp);
}`

Comment: hmm I mean it works flawless. Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: This is an example of "works on my machine". If you run this on another operating system, splitting each folder as a separate argument solves issues. Similarly if you run the code from a different CWD/PWD, then the `process.cwd()` will no longer be relative. So use `__dirname`. If this code will only ever be ran on your machine, in the same way every time, then it will continue to work *for you*. Change it to my example if you want it to work *for everyone*.